# prints an error Fatal error: Array index is out of range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I created a function that calculates the min and max. Created an array, called a function, but throws an error:

```
Fatal error: Array index is out of range
Current stack trace:
0    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f685ed39920 _swift_stdlib_reportFatalError + 69
1    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f685ec47a06 <unavailable> + 3279366
2    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f685ec47d85 <unavailable> + 3280261
3    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f685ec65c83 <unavailable> + 3402883
4    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f685ea996a1 <unavailable> + 1517217
5    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f685ea5a289 <unavailable> + 1258121
6    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f685eb74d00 MutableCollection.subscript.getter + 235
7    main                               0x0000563fff1260b3 <unavailable> + 45235
8    main                               0x0000563fff124c23 <unavailable> + 39971
9    libc.so.6                          0x00007f685dc18ab0 __libc_start_main + 231
10   main                               0x0000563fff11d4ea <unavailable> + 9450
exited, illegal instruction
```

here is my code:

```
  func minMax(Array: [Int]) -> (min: Int, max: Int) { 
    var currentMin = Array[0]
    var currentMax = Array[0]
    for value in Array[1 ... Array.count] {
        if value < currentMin {
            currentMin = value
            } else if value > currentMax {
                currentMax = value
            }
    }
    return(currentMin, currentMax)
}
let bounds = minMax(Array: [8, -6, 2, 109, 3, 71])
print("min is \(bounds.min) and max is \(bounds.max)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `..<` when iterating through the elements in the array from `0` to `array.count` not `...` which tried to get the element corresponding to index at `array.count` which is out of bound.

```
func minMax(Array: [Int]) -> (min: Int, max: Int) {
    if Array.isEmpty { fatalError("Empty array!!") } // or you could return (0, 0) if that's what you want.
    var currentMin = Array[0]
    var currentMax = Array[0]
    for value in Array[1 ..< Array.count] {
        if value < currentMin {
            currentMin = value
            } else if value > currentMax {
                currentMax = value
            }
    }
    return(currentMin, currentMax)
}
```

Better Approach: The better approach is to use `.min` and `.max` properties:

```
func minMax(Array: [Int]) -> (min: Int?, max: Int?) { (Array.min(), Array.max())
```

Comment: What happens if the array is empty?

Comment: Thanks for noticing that edge case.

Comment: It's not an edge case, it is a basic check and specially when accessing the array using a hardcoded index.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get an illegal `index` of the array and that is `Array[array.count]` which is not in the range.

You should consider iterate over elements of the array **directly** to avoid these issues:

```
for value in Array {
    ,,,
}
```

Also, you may have a crash if the array is empty on `Array[0]`. So check for empty array condition first.

So the refactored code will be:

```
func minMax(array: [Int]) -> (min: Int, max: Int) {
    guard var currentMin = array.first else { fatalError("An empty array could not have min or max") } // Handle this error as you like
    var currentMax = currentMin
    for value in array {
        if value < currentMin {
            currentMin = value
        } else if value > currentMax {
            currentMax = value
        }
    }
    return(currentMin, currentMax)
}
let bounds = minMax(array: [8, -6, 2, 109, 3, 71])
print("min is \(bounds.min) and max is \(bounds.max)")
```

---

## Default .min() and .max() implementation

You may consider using default `min` and `max` functions of the `array`:

```
func minMax(array: [Int]) -> (min: Int?, max: Int?) { (array.min(), array.max()) }
```